# Bot Framework returning to wrong dialog

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I've got a stubborn problem trying to forward a message to a FormFlow dialog from within a LUIS dialog. The code I'm using to do so is:

```
var timeRegistrationDialog = new FormDialog<TimeRegistrationDialog>(new TimeRegistrationDialog(), TimeRegistrationDialog.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, entities);
context.Call<TimeRegistrationDialog>(timeRegistrationDialog, this.ResumeAfterTimeRegistration);
```

This seems to be in line with the samples out there. What happens next though

- The form flow dialog is created
- The bot asks for the first field
- I enter a valid value
- When sent, the default LUIS intent triggers instead of the next step of the form flow

This is probably also related to what I posted here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1956. Probably not a bug but an error on my part; trying to resume a conversation from an oauth callback also fails because the framework seems unable to locate the right dialog. I based it completely on the AuthBot sample which seems super similar but doesn't have the issue.

So in general, it appears that I'm doing something wrong that causes the wrong dialog to be returned from the stack (or no dialog at all). I just have no clue what. A not up-to-date version of the code is located here: https://github.com/mstack/bots-jennifer. Not up-to-date, but has similar issues so should be sufficient to track any errors. Should any more be required I can post it.